# Makefile for arbitrary latex document

Tags: makefile

I wanna use automatic variables to prepare a Makefile for several latex documents.

In other words, i have foo.tex, bar.tex, bee.tex, otherdoc.tex ...

I wanna use a single Makefile to process all of them in the same manner, say  process with latex, dvips, ps2pdf ...

I do not want to process all of them at once, but individually.

The base name of my project, say foo.tex, will be supplied at the command line when running make. Reading this basename from the command line is my problem at the moment.

How do i do that?

Sure i can write a Makefile for each document, but it sucks ...

Thx a lot

Comment: Take a look at latexmk.

Comment: @user152037 You can have a variable declaration such as `SRC_BASE_NAME := default-name` in your `Makefile` (with stuff such as `SRC           := $(SRC_BASE_NAME).tex` and `$(SRC_BASE_NAME).pdf: $(SRC) etc.` ← rule that describes how to produce a PDF file from `$(SRC)`). Then you can call Make like this: `make SRC_BASE_NAME=foobar` in order to produce `foobar.pdf` from `foobar.tex`. Not sure the Make-fu is on topic here, though.

Comment: @user152037 Note: since I used `make SRC_BASE_NAME=foobar` on the command line in my example, this just sets the `SRC_BASE_NAME` Make variable and builds the default target of the `Makefile`; but I didn't say what the *default target* is. This is the first target in the `Makefile`. Therefore, with my notations, you could start your `Makefile` with, for instance, `.PHONY: all` and `all: $(SRC_BASE_NAME).pdf` or, in case you also defined rules following the same pattern to produce, say, DVI output: `all: $(SRC_BASE_NAME).pdf $(SRC_BASE_NAME).dvi`.

Comment: @user152037 I've put a sample `Makefile` illustrating this [on pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/ztq1s632) (it has other improvements I didn't describe here), but you'll have to recover the tab characters: they have all been destroyed by the stupid site (or HTML browser). AFAIK, sites from the stackexchange network also eat tabs in the Markdown, so there wouldn't be that much to gain by posting it here. With this `Makefile`, you can write on the command line `make`, `make SRC_BASE_NAME=foobar`, `make pdf`, `make SRC_BASE_NAME=foobar pdf ps`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I really advise using [`latexmk`](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html) (or similar tools, like `arara`).

The reason is that `latexmk` will automatically track dependencies for you, it will know if the document need recompilation or not, and will call the various `bibtex` & Co. without having to write complex tests in Makefile.

Moreover, it can run in background, so that the document is automatically compiled and the preview refreshed every time you save the document, and it is normally well integrated in editors (works a treat with `vim` and [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)).